# add class in Magic Slider

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, php

I want to add a class to theme, how can i fined the file path ? or is there another way to add class ?

here is the class
class="slide-home alo-magicslider"

i want to add continer to this class

class="slide-home alo-magicslider **container**"

Answer (score 0):

**Hello,**

Please do, download that extension, it will help you out!

https://store.webkul.com/Magic-Slideshow-Magento2.html